# insert form fields to DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a custom form post and data are sent to email as per below code. However my insert statement to DB does not seem to work. And, the table called 'leads' in my DB is still empty.
I pretty much followed the example from: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
Any pointers would be appreciated to get this sql insert work,

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if($_POST){

$to = 'myemailaddres@example.com';

$subject = 'Website Enquiry';
$now = new DateTime();
$datesent=$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments =  $_POST['comments'];    
$fname =  $_POST['fname'];  

$username = "usertest";
$password = "pwdtest";
$dbname = "dbtest";
$servername = "localhost";


//spam checks

if ( isset($fname) && !isset($fname) ) {
    echo 'spam';
    exit();
} elseif ( preg_match("/http/i","$comments")  ){ 
    echo '<h1>Spam detected</h1><p>Sorry, no urls allowed in comment box.</p>';
    exit(); 
}

$data = clean($_POST);

if(validate($data) == 0){

    $email = $data['email'];
    $headers = "From: ".$data['name']." <".$email.">\r\n".
    "Bcc: <".$bcc.">\r\n".
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


    if($data['form'] == 'quote') {
        $subject = 'Quick quote - '.$subject; 
    }else if($data['form'] == 'enquiry') {
        $subject = 'Enquiry Form - '.$subject; 
    }else{
        $subject = 'Enquiry Form - '.$subject; 
    }

    foreach ($data as $k => $v) { 
        if($k != "Submit" && $k != "form" && $k != "fname" && $k != "quiz" && $k != "captcha_code"){
            $k = str_replace ( "_" , " " , $k );
            $message .= $k.": ".$v."\n\r"; 
        }
    }

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){

        /****** TEST SEND TO DB ***********/


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO leads (name, telephone, email, date)
VALUES ($name, $telephone, $email, $datesent)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();



/********* END TEST SEND TO DB *****/

        header("Location: /thank-you"); 
    } else {
        //echo 'Mail Error';
        header("Location: /error");

    }

}else{
    //echo 'Validate Error';
    header("Location: /error"); 
}

}else{
    //echo 'Post Error';
    header("Location: /error");
}

function clean($post){
    $remove = array('vin');
    $data = array();

    foreach($post as $key => $value){

        if(in_array($value,$remove)){
            $data[$key] = '';
        }else{
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return array_filter($data);
}

function validate($data){
    $error = array();

    if (!preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $data['email'])) {
      //    $error[] = '1';
    }

    if ((strlen($data['name']) < 1) || (strlen($data['name']) > 32)) {
        //$error[] = '1';
    }

    if ((strlen($data['telephone']) < 10)) {
        $error[] = '1';
        echo 'Please enter 10 digit numbers for telephone number';
    }



    if(isset($data['form'])){
        if($data['form'] == 'quote'){
            if ((strlen($data['address']) < 1)) {
                // $error[] = '1';
            }
        }
    }

    return count($error);
}

?>
```

Comment: it will easy to answer if you give us your proper error message

Answer (score 2):

I assume name, telephone, email, and date are of string types, put quotes if its a string

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO leads (name, telephone, email, date)
VALUES ('$name', '$telephone', '$email', '$datesent')";
```

Comment: Thank you Vidya, that was the mistake I made, I forgot the quotes for strings. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

User correct way of string concatenation while concatenating php variable and string.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO leads (name, telephone, email, date)
VALUES ('".$name."', '".$telephone."', '".$email."', '".$datesent."')";
```